# Perl regex rename

Tags: regex, perl, rename

I'm trying to set the first letter of the files of a directory to uppercase.
I tried [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html):

```
rename -n 's/^[a-z]/\U$1/' *
```

but it removes the first character instead.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Perl's [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) doesn't have an `-n` parameter. What exactly are you using? Bash rename?

Comment: Yes, but it uses perl regex

Answer (score 7):

You didn't create a capturing group:

```
rename -n 's/^([a-z])/\U$1/' *
              ^     ^
```